# Google Calendar API - List Event with startDate and EndDate Filter

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-api, google-calendar-api

I can't understand how Google Calender Event List work with timeMin and timeMax parameter.I am using the following statement for filter events. (Used Google Calender V3 API)

```
service.events().list(calendarId='primary',timeMin=start_dt,timeMax=end_dt)
```

I have created event from 23-12-2013 to 26-12-2013 without specifying time.

Now when I specified `timeMax=2013-12-23T00:00:00+05:30` and `timeMin=2013-12-23T00:00:00+05:30` then and only then I have got event in list if I specified timeMin greater than 23 it gives me `event['items']=[]`. Also not understand timezone.

Can anyone help me to understand this.

Comment: Not related to appengine or python. Its about calendar api.